# Use a checkbox to add a name to a array

Tags: java, arrays, checkbox

This is the first time i really can't figure out how something works. 
So i thought i'll ask it here. I have searched and searched but i could not found what i wanted.

I am working on a small program that picks a random name out of 7 names. 
I created a window and a interface.

What i want to do is, i want to check if a checkbox is selected.
`ButtonAnne.setSelection(true);`
When the checkbox is selected i want to add a name to a array.
And when the box is deselected it should not be in that array.

So the full piece of code from 1 checkbox looks like this:

```
Button ButtonAnne = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK);
    ButtonAnne.setSelection(true);
    ButtonAnne.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
    ButtonAnne.setBounds(122, 56, 188, 34);
    ButtonAnne.setText("Aanwezig of afwezig");
```

Eventually when a button is clicked it will choose a random name out of the names where the checkbox is selected (so the names that are added in the array). But thats for another time.

Do you guys have any idea how i can accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Arrays are not resizable in Java, look into `ArrayList`s

Comment: Then I maybe should create a second class, Where I check the checkboxes with if-else statements.

if checkbox is selected add name to arraylist.
else remove from arraylist.

something like that.

Comment: yes you can do that! But you don't have to create a class for that. You can write a small function as well.

Comment: Hmmm, I think i will create a second class for it because that keeps the code clean and easier to read for myself. Although creating a small function for it might be faster and easier overall.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this piece of code so far. 
No errors yet. So i am guessing it will work.

```
public void Button(int style[])
{
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(ButtonAnne.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Anne");
        }
        if(ButtonBas.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Bas");
        }
        if(ButtonDaan.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Daan");
        }
        if(ButtonNick.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Nick");
        }
        if(ButtonPaul.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Paul");
        }
        if(ButtonPeter.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Peter");
        }
        if(ButtonSebastien.getSelection() == true) {
            names.add("Sebastien");
    }
}
```

If my brain is right. It will check the checkbox selection befor putting the names into the arraylist.
If the chackbox is not checked it shouldnt be doing anything. But we will see when everything works out.